# YUM Upgrade when package name changes

Tags: yum

The API Gateway Kong decided to change the name of their Centos package.

For versions up to 1.1 its "kong-community-edition", after that the package name is just "kong".

```
kong-community-edition.noarch            1.0.2-1                bintray--kong-kong-rpm
kong-community-edition.noarch            1.0.3-1                bintray--kong-kong-rpm
kong-community-edition.noarch            1.1.0rc1-1             bintray--kong-kong-rpm
kong.noarch                              1.2.1-1                bintray--kong-kong-rpm
kong.noarch                              1.2.2-1                bintray--kong-kong-rpm
kong.x86_64                              1.3.0-1                bintray--kong-kong-rpm
```

Can I somehow tell YUM to upgrade the current installation of kong-community-edition 1.1 to the kong 1.3 package?

I've tried upgrading the currently installed version (1.1.0rc1-1)

```
yum upgrade kong-community-edition
```

but it reports that no upgrade is available.

I've also tried to upgrade specifically to the new version

```
yum upgrade kong-1.3.0-1
```

but that reports that Kong isn't installed.

I've also tried to use install to install the new version.

```
yum install kong-1.3.0-1
```

but that reports conflicts with the files that were created by kong-community-edition.

Is there any way I can tell yum that the version following kong-community-edition-1.1.0rc1-1 is actually kong-1.2.1-1 so I can use yum upgrade.

At the moment the only option I seem to have is to delete the kong-community-edition package and add the kong package fresh

```
yum remove kong-community-edition
yum install kong
```

but I was hoping to do an in place upgrade instead.

**Answer:**

As a user of the packages it can't be done.  The kong package needs to properly identify that it obsoletes the kong-community-edition package and that needs to be done by the package maintainer.

To work around:  remove kong-community-edition, install kong

Comment: couldn't understand your question, can you add what you tried and not worked any errors? Are you looking for repo changes or just yum command?

Comment: @asktyagi  I've expanded the question.   I'm after yum commands because the repo belongs to someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the kong rpm and run `rpm -q --obsoletes kong-1.3.0.rhel7.amd64.rpm` you will see that "kong-community-edition" is not present. Hence, `yum install kong` does not know to remove ""kong-community-edition". You'll have to do a remove and install.

If you look at the repo https://github.com/Kong/kong-build-tools.git you can see fpm is used to build the rpm in `fpm-entrypoint.sh` around line 38 and the invocation of `fpm` does not include `--replaces` which translates into obsoletes in rpm lingo.